# How to make eyelids go up and down instead of rotating

Tags: modeling

So yeah how would I do that, upper lid would cover 70-80% of eye from top and I want to move the up and down but there is trouble I don't know how to make lid stick to eye because if I moved it now it would go into eye when bottom of lid comes to middle of eye I need ti to stick to surface of eye at any position and one more trouble is that when I move it up/down it was going trought rest of mesh (let's say face), so how would I make it go up and down and dissolve at top in order not to go thru rest of face, I know it somehow possible with lattice but I can't figure how.? Any toughts?

[image]

[image]

Brown plane represents the face, you got the rest of it.